# how to get access to the path directory in FLUTTER WEB as final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); doesn't seem to work

Tags: flutter

how to get access to the path directory in FLUTTER WEB as final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); doesn't seem to work ... This is required to generate pdf invoice.

Answer (score 1):

- The web does not have internal file storage or acces a device,
  information can only be stored through cookies or a database such as
  Indexeddb.
- You can create the invoice by creating the file with dart code and then send it or share it by some means
- Another way would be to create it through a canvas.

Comment: thank you for the answer... as you suggested i just uploaded file to fireStore and then fetched it then again launched it.

Answer (score 0):

i just uploaded the file to fireStore and then fetched it then again launched it using http package. or i found out we can launch the url also with launcher package.